# Preserve data order when using count() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a Coursera student learning R. I realize that this particular question has been covered on SO before; however, I did not see anyone else try at approach the problem using the dplyr package.

Desired Output:

```
> complete("specdata", 332:1)[1:2,]
     id nobs
313 332  301
312 331  353>
```

Present Output:

```
> complete("specdata", 332:1)[1:2,]
   ID nobs
1 332  301
2 331  353
>
```

My Function:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
        airpolutionfiles <- list.files("assignment1data/specdata", full.names=TRUE)
        monitorsdata_all <- data.frame()
        for (i in 1:332) {
        monitorsdata_all <- rbind(monitorsdata_all, read.csv(airpolutionfiles[i]))
        }
        monitorsdata_all_subset <- subset(monitorsdata_all, complete.cases(monitorsdata_all) & ID %in% id)
        countbyid <- count(monitorsdata_all_subset, "ID")
        nobs <- rename(countbyid, c("freq"="nobs"))
        arrange(nobs, desc(ID))
}
```

I have seen many solutions on SO that try and change the way the multiple data files are binded / looped. While I realize that as written the way my function is doing that is sub-optimal, I'd request that any help you provide doesn't mess around with that as I'm still trying to get a grip on the basics.

So my question comes down to... after subsetting using:

```
monitorsdata_all_subset <- subset(monitorsdata_all, complete.cases(monitorsdata_all) & ID %in% id)
```

Is there anyway to count observations by group (in this case id) and preserve the relative position of the ID column vs. the row#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
        airpolutionfiles <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
        nobs <- c()
        for (i in 1:length(id)) {
        monitorsdata_all <- read.csv(airpolutionfiles[id[i]])
        nobs[i] <- sum(complete.cases(monitorsdata_all))
        }
        data.frame(id, nobs)
}
```

In your original code you make a few choices that slow down your progress. You didn't use the `directory` argument ( I think that was an oversight when writing the example). You also `rbind` all of the files after they are read in to R. I wouldn't do that. Especially reading in files that you are not going to use.

```
for ( i in 1:332) {
```

It is very slow. Even if the person has `id=1`, you will be reading in every file just to get to that one. Why not just read in the id files that the user chose.

Next, we count the number of complete observations *inside* the loop instead of outside of it. That way we have a loop that is collecting observations not data frames.

```
sum(complete.cases(monitorsdata_all))
```

That command will count the number of complete observations. After that `nobs` variable is created, it is easy to combine with the ids that the user chose.

---

**bonus**

You wanted to see how you could do an operation by group. I added four ways to group an operation in R. There are even more than that.

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
        airpolutionfiles <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
        monitorsdata_all <- data.frame()
        for (i in id) {
        monitorsdata_all <- rbind(monitorsdata_all, read.csv(airpolutionfiles[i]))
        }
        df <- subset(monitorsdata_all, complete.cases(monitorsdata_all))

        #one way to count number of ids
        nobs <- table(df$ID)

        #a different approach. I use "sulfate" but I could have used any column (they all have the same length)
        nobs <- tapply(df$sulfate, df$ID, length)

        #Two more ways with aggregate. I add [,2] after bc it is a data frame and I want the second column
        nobs <- aggregate(sulfate ~ ID, df, length)[,2]

        nobs <- aggregate(df$sulfate, list(df$ID), length)[,2]

        #then combine
        data.frame(id, nobs)
}
```

Comment: Regarding directory, the Course has you use a submit() which tests your function against where they think "directory" should be, because my data folder is in a sub-folder they don't know the name of I didn't bother to use the directory variable.

Comment: You shouldn't create variables and not use them. You are trying to shortcut the lesson. You can use `setwd("assignment1data/")` above the function. When `submit()` calls `complete.R` it will use the correct directory path.

Comment: Agreed on wd. You're code is definitely more elegant and works a lot faster while preserving row order. In general, I think I'm just frustrated with how difficult I'm finding the whole "group by" functionality in R as compare to let say SQL. 

I tired the sum(complete.cases in the way that I was subsetting before and it worked, but only if the id variable was a single value not a sequence, which would result in the sum of the entire sequence not each id.

Comment: I will add a piece on grouped functions.

Comment: I added four more ways to group operations.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Imma change your code first so I can figure out what you're asking

```
library(dplyr)

data = 
  "assignment1data/specdata" %>%
  list.files(full.names=TRUE) %>%
  { data_frame(file = .) } %>%
  mutate(order_in_folder = 1:n() ) %>%
  group_by(file, order_in_folder) %>%
  do( read.csv(file) )

frequency = 
  data %>%
  group_by(ID, order_in_folder) %>%
  summarize(nobs = n() ) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(order_in_folder)
```

Comment: I think you been hitting the pipe a little too hard ;p

Comment: End the drug/data.table vs. dplyr war!